# Join with all months in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(o.sale_on),
       SUM(od.current_status_id=1) AS Sales,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=2) AS Refunds,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=3) AS `Partially Refunded`,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=4) AS `Pending`,
       SUM(od.price-IFNULL(od.discount,0)+IFNULL(od.additional_charges,0)) AS net_revenue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN od.current_status_id=1 THEN od.price-IFNULL(od.discount,0)+IFNULL(od.additional_charges,0) END) AS gross_revenue
FROM orders o 
   RIGHT JOIN order_detail od USING (order_id)
where 1=1
  and year(o.sale_on) = 2015
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(o.sale_on,'%Y-%m')
ORDER BY o.sale_on
```

that return data like this

```
MONTHNAME(o.sale_on) |  Sales | Refunds | PartiallyRefunded | Pending | net_revenue  | gross_revenue

January              |   67   | 0       |0                  |   0     | 5971.1600    | 5971.1600

February             |  1644  | 1       |0                  |   0     | 152.7200     |152.7200

March                |   39   |     0   |0                  |0        |0.0000        |  0.0000
```

I want to show it for all the months , how can I do that ?

Another query I tried in which made a join with master_months table

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(o.sale_on),
       mo.month_name,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=1) AS Sales,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=2) AS Refunds,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=3) AS `Partially Refunded`,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=4) AS `Pending`,
       SUM(od.priceIFNULL(od.discount,0)+IFNULL(od.additional_charges,0)) AS net_revenue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN od.current_status_id=1 THEN od.price-IFNULL(od.discount,0)+IFNULL(od.additional_charges,0) END) AS gross_revenue
FROM master_months mo 
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON mo.month_name = MONTHNAME(o.sale_on)
  RIGHT JOIN order_detail od USING (order_id) 
WHERE 1=1
  AND YEAR(o.sale_on) = 2015
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(o.sale_on,'%Y-%m')
ORDER BY o.sale_on
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `left join` and `right join` in a query is just confusing.  You want a chain of `left join`, starting with the table that has all the months.  All the rest of the joins should be `left join`.

Then, your `where` clause is undoing the `left join`.  You need to move the condition on the year to an `on` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM master_months mo LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON mo.month_name = MONTHNAME(o.sale_on) AND
        YEAR(o.sale_on) = 2015 LEFT JOIN
     order_detail od
     ON o.order_id = od.order_id
GROUP BY mo.month_name
ORDER BY mo.month_name
```

Comment: it just added only the 'December' month with all other values as null.